# Jetty is not receiving http request from outside on ec2

Tags: amazon-ec2, jetty

I've configured jetty hightide 8.1 server on ec2 instance. My jetty.xml file is as follows

```
<Configure id="Server" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server">

    <!-- =========================================================== -->
    <!-- Server Thread Pool                                          -->
    <!-- =========================================================== -->
    <Set name="ThreadPool">
      <!-- Default queued blocking threadpool -->
      <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool">
        <Set name="minThreads">10</Set>
        <Set name="maxThreads">200</Set>
        <Set name="detailedDump">false</Set>
      </New>
    </Set>

    <!-- =========================================================== -->
    <!-- Set connectors                                              -->
    <!-- =========================================================== -->

    <Call name="addConnector">
      <Arg>
          <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.nio.SelectChannelConnector">
            <Set name="host"><Property name="jetty.host" default="0.0.0.0"/></Set>
            <Set name="port"><Property name="jetty.port" default="80"/></Set>
            <Set name="maxIdleTime">300000</Set>
            <Set name="Acceptors">2</Set>
            <Set name="statsOn">false</Set>
            <Set name="confidentialPort">8443</Set>
            <Set name="lowResourcesConnections">20000</Set>
            <Set name="lowResourcesMaxIdleTime">5000</Set>
          </New>
      </Arg>
    </Call>

    <!-- =========================================================== -->
    <!-- Set handler Collection Structure                            -->
    <!-- =========================================================== -->
    <Set name="handler">
      <New id="Handlers" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection">
        <Set name="handlers">
         <Array type="org.eclipse.jetty.server.Handler">
           <Item>
             <New id="Contexts" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection"/>
           </Item>
           <Item>
             <New id="DefaultHandler" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.DefaultHandler"/>
           </Item>
                   <Item>
                         <New id="RequestLog" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.RequestLogHandler"/>
                   </Item>
         </Array>
        </Set>
      </New>
    </Set>

        <Call name="addBean">
      <Arg>
        <New id="DeploymentManager" class="org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager">
          <Set name="contexts">
            <Ref id="Contexts" />
          </Set>
          <Call name="setContextAttribute">
            <Arg>org.eclipse.jetty.server.webapp.ContainerIncludeJarPattern</Arg>
            <Arg>.*/servlet-api-[^/]*\.jar$</Arg>
          </Call>


          <!-- Add a customize step to the deployment lifecycle -->
          <!-- uncomment and replace DebugBinding with your extended AppLifeCycle.Binding class
          <Call name="insertLifeCycleNode">
            <Arg>deployed</Arg>
            <Arg>starting</Arg>
            <Arg>customise</Arg>
          </Call>
          <Call name="addLifeCycleBinding">
            <Arg>
              <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.bindings.DebugBinding">
                <Arg>customise</Arg>
              </New>
            </Arg>
          </Call>
          -->

        </New>
      </Arg>
    </Call>

        <Ref id="DeploymentManager">
          <Call name="addAppProvider">
                <Arg>
                  <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ContextProvider">
                        <Set name="monitoredDirName"><Property name="jetty.home" default="." />/contexts</Set>
                        <Set name="scanInterval">1</Set>
                  </New>
                </Arg>
          </Call>
        </Ref>

        <Ref id="RequestLog">
          <Set name="requestLog">
                <New id="RequestLogImpl" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.NCSARequestLog">
                  <Arg><SystemProperty name="jetty.logs" default="./logs"/>/yyyy_mm_dd.tutorial.log</Arg>
                  <Set name="retainDays">90</Set>
                  <Set name="append">true</Set>
                  <Set name="extended">false</Set>
                  <Set name="LogTimeZone">GMT</Set>
                </New>
          </Set>
        </Ref>
    <!-- =========================================================== -->
    <!-- extra options                                               -->
    <!-- =========================================================== -->
    <Set name="stopAtShutdown">true</Set>
    <Set name="sendServerVersion">true</Set>
    <Set name="sendDateHeader">true</Set>
    <Set name="gracefulShutdown">1000</Set>
    <Set name="dumpAfterStart">false</Set>
    <Set name="dumpBeforeStop">false</Set>

</Configure>
```

And in /contexts folder I've made a file mydomain.xml as follows

```
<Configure class="org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext">


  <!-- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -->
  <!-- Required minimal context configuration :                        -->
  <!--  + contextPath                                                  -->
  <!--  + war OR resourceBase                                          -->
  <!-- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -->
  <Set name="contextPath">/</Set>
  <Set name="resourceBase"><SystemProperty name="jetty.home" default="."/>/webapps/sampleapp/</Set>

  <!-- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -->
  <!-- Optional context configuration                                  -->
  <!-- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -->
  <Set name="extractWAR">true</Set>
  <Set name="copyWebDir">false</Set>

  <!-- virtual hosts -->
  <Set name="virtualHosts">
    <Array type="String">
      <Item>www.mydomain.com</Item>
      <Item>localhost</Item>
      <Item>127.0.0.1</Item>
    </Array>
  </Set>
  <!-- Virtual Hosts-->

  <!-- disable cookies
  <Get name="sessionHandler">
     <Get name="sessionManager">
        <Set name="usingCookies" type="boolean">false</Set>
     </Get>
  </Get>
  -->

  <!-- Non standard error page mapping -->
  <!--
  <Get name="errorHandler">
    <Call name="addErrorPage">
      <Arg type="int">500</Arg>
      <Arg type="int">599</Arg>
      <Arg type="String">/dump/errorCodeRangeMapping</Arg>
    </Call>
  </Get>
  -->

  <!-- Add context specific logger
  <Set name="handler">
    <New id="RequestLog" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.RequestLogHandler">
      <Set name="requestLog">
        <New id="RequestLogImpl" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.NCSARequestLog">
          <Set name="filename"><Property name="jetty.logs" default="./logs"/>/test-yyyy_mm_dd.request.log</Set>
          <Set name="filenameDateFormat">yyyy_MM_dd</Set>
          <Set name="append">true</Set>
          <Set name="LogTimeZone">GMT</Set>
        </New>
      </Set>
    </New>
  </Set>
  -->

</Configure>
```

When I'm doing wget from the ec2 instance I'm getting proper index.html page. But if I do it from outside or hit www.mydomain.com from the browser I'm getting request timed out. I've set jetty to listen to http port 80 but no request from outside is coming to jetty. I've created the CNAME record in my domain registrar with the public dns provided in the aws console. IP and dns is resolved correctly but jetty doesn't receive any request. I'm not able to understand the problem in my configuration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, All the configurations are correct. Actually tcp port 80 was not open from aws console. I just wasted 2 hours to realize that.